# Using Nokogiri with XML files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have this XML:

```
<Experiment>
<mzData version="1.05" accessionNumber="1635">
<description>
<admin>
<sampleName>Fas-induced and control Jurkat T-lymphocytes</sampleName> 
<sampleDescription>
<cvParam cvLabel="MeSH" accession="D017209" name="apoptosis" /> 
<cvParam cvLabel="UNITY" accession="D2135" name="Jurkat cells" /> 
<cvParam cvLabel="MeSH" accession="D019014" name="Antigens, CD95" /> 
</sampleDescription>
</admin>
</description>
</mzData>
</Experiment>
</ExperimentCollection>
```

I also have the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("my.xml"))

sampleName = doc.xpath( "/ExperimentCollection/Experiment/mzData/description/admin/sampleName" ).text
sampleDescription = doc.xpath( "/ExperimentCollection/Experiment/mzData/description/admin/sampleDescription/MeSH/@accession" ).text
puts sampleName + " " + sampleDescription

foo = sampleName + " " + sampleDescription 
f = File.new("my.txt","w")
f.write(foo) 
f.close()
```

The code grabs the `sampleName` just fine, but not the `accession` letters/numbers. I only want to grab all the letters/numbers after `MeSH` -> `accession` (`D017209` and `D019014`). What do I have to change in the `doc.xpath` command to make this work?

Comment: you should add an xpath tag to your question

Comment: So it seems that I'm not the only person using Nokogiri's xpath to get data from ms files. I've updated things to mzML though. Just kind of interesting to see since I usually see people use C code for these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc.xpath( "/ExperimentCollection/Experiment/mzData/description/admin/sampleDescription/MeSH/@accession" )
```

Returns nothing because there is no tag `MeSH`. You need to replace `MeSH` with `cvParam[@cvLabel=\"MeSH\"]` (read: a `cvParam` tag which has an attribute `cvLabel` with the value `MeSH`).

Once you fixed that `xpath` will return a collection of `Nokogiri::XML::Attr` objects. By calling text on that collection you will get back the string value of the first element. Since you want all of the elements you should instead use `map(&:text)` (or `map {|n| n.text}` in ruby 1.8.6) which will return an array containing the string value of each `accession` attribute (i.e. `["D017209", "D019014"]` for the example XML-file).

Since you seem to be confused, here's a clarification:

@Bobby: When I said "`xpath` will return a collection of `Nokogiri::XML::Attr`  objects", I meant just that. You call `xpath` and then `xpath` creates and returns a collection of `Attr` objects. In no way did I mean that you should manually create any `Attr` objects yourself.

And when I said you should use `map`, I just meant you should call `map` on the collection returned by `xpath` (though instead of using `map` you can just call `puts` with the collection as an argument).

1. So what you need to do is 1. fix your xpath like I described.
2. use `xpath` with the fixed xpath to get a collection
3. use puts to print it

In other words:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("my.xml"))

common_prefix = "/ExperimentCollection/Experiment/mzData/description/admin"
sample_name = doc.xpath( common_prefix+"/sampleName" ).text
accessions = doc.xpath( common_prefix+
               "/sampleDescription/cvParam[@cvLabel=\"MeSH\"]/@accession" )

puts sample_name
puts accessions
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. What commands can I use to call upon Nokogiri::XML::Attr objects?

Comment: @Bobby: To get their values just use `value` or `text`. There are of course many other things you can do with Attr objects (basically all the things you can do with any Node object - get its parent for example). They're all documented on the API page for [XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).

Comment: Say I wanted to just save the text into a variable, then display it. Shouldn't something like this should work then?      

     m = Nokogiri::XML::Attr

    puts m

Comment: @Bobby: Well, no because you're setting `m` to the class `Nokogiri::XML::Attr`, not to an instance of it. But yes, if `m` points to an `Attr`, `puts m` will work.

Comment: Here is the code so far from what u gave me:

    sampleDescription = doc.xpath( "/ExperimentCollection/Experiment/mzData/description/admin/sampleDescription/cvParam[@cvLabel=\"MeSH\"]" ).text
    Nokogiri::XML::Attr(map(&:text))
    m = accession
    puts m

So more like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it, although this is probably too clever, because you'll probably want to do other things as well:

```
File.open("my.txt","w") do |f|
  doc.xpath('//cvParam[@cvLabel="MeSH"]').each {|n| f << "#{n['name']} #{n['accession']}\n"}
end
```

You may need a more selective xpath statement.